# Textbox Filling all available space in Grid Row

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm experiencing a problem with my UI XAML code. The problem is that I can't get my `TextBox` to fill in all available space in the Grid Row that contains it. I read quite a few posts about similar issues, and the summary of them is "don't use stack panel for this" and "set `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`", but this did not work for me. Near the bottom of my XAML you can see the text box that I've been trying to get to stretch to fill the height of the grid row, along with the text box I'm hoping to have work by the end in a comment.

Having `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` does not change the behavior of the XAML, and produces a one-line `TextBox` as if I didn't assign `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` at all. This is what the GUI page looks like with or without `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`:

[image]

Here is the respective XAML code.

```
<ContentControl x:Class="Analytics.Configuration.UI.DataflowTemplateView"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ComputersUnlimited.Analytics.Configuration.UI"
            xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
            xmlns:core="http://schemas.cu.net/2011/xaml/presentation/core"
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
            d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
            d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:DataflowTemplateViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Row0">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding NavigateToPreviousControlCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,20,0">Back</Button>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="M-Code Template Text" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

    </Grid>

    <!--<TextBox Grid.Row="1"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             Margin="0,6,0,6"
             AcceptsReturn="True"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>-->
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

</Grid>
```

I've tried all the advice I've ran into with no success. So, if you have any advice, sharing would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely there is an implicit style for `TextBox` that is setting a default `Height`. If that's the case, you'll need to set:

`Height="NaN"`

On your `TextBox` in order for it to stretch.

Comment: THAT WAS IT. Thank you. But now I'm wondering why? What is an implicit style, when are they applied, etc. I'll look up "XAML implicit styles" unless you have a better recommendation. Thanks again.

Comment: An implicit style doesn't have a key. It looks something like `<Style TargetType="TextBox"><Setter Property="Height" Value="20" /></Style>`. Most likely it is in a `ResourceDictionary` that's merged in `App.xaml` or somewhere else in your app. If you're using a 3rd party theme, it could be there too.